# Preload() custom JoinTable Gorm.io for SQL-SELECT

Tags: sqlite, go, preload, go-gorm

I just do have a question about **Gorm.io** for **Go**:

I do have a nested DB-Struct with custom JoinTable (M2M).

With my SQL-Select I'd like to *Preload()* the full data from custom JoinTable.
But I didn't get it working so far.

**My DB:**

```
var Db *gorm.DB

type Players struct {
    Player_ID              int         `gorm:"primaryKey;index"`
    UserName               string
    Is_Online              bool
    Ready                  bool
}
type Game struct {
    Game_ID                int         `gorm:"primaryKey;index"`
    Players                []Players   `gorm:"many2many:game_players"`
}

// Custom JoinTable
type GamePlayers struct {
    Game_Game_ID           int         `gorm:"primaryKey;index"`
    Players_Player_ID      string      `gorm:"primaryKey;index"`
    TablePlaceNumber       int
}

func main(){
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    Db = db
    
    Db.SetupJoinTable(&Game{}, "Players", &GamePlayers{})

    Db.AutoMigrate(&Players{}, &Game{})
}
```

**My Select (select Game by a Player and show all Players from the Game):**

```
var game Game
// for better reading, I removed quotes for String
const sqlSelectCurrentGame = SELECT *
  FROM games
  INNER JOIN game_players ON game_players.game_game_id = games.game_id
  INNER JOIN players ON game_players.players_pk_player_id = players.pk_player_id
  WHERE games.game_id = (SELECT games.game_id
    FROM games
    INNER JOIN game_players ON game_players.game_game_id = games.game_id
    WHERE game_players.players_player_id = 1)
  ORDER BY game_players.table_place_number ASC

Db.Raw(sqlSelectCurrentGame).Preload("Players").Find(&game)
```

The Select does returning the structure **Game** with array of participating **Game-Players** as nested **Players-struct** with **Players-attributes**.

But my goal is to get the data from custom JoinTable **GamePlayers** as well.

Is there a possibility, to reach my goal?

Thank you an BR
Phil

Comment: try `Preload("GamePlayers")`

Comment: also can you able to post data means in which format you getting data ?

Comment: Can you replace `Db.` with `Db.Debug().` in your last line and check what SQL it's actually running. I have a suspicion your custom query isn't really executing because `Raw` cannot be used with `Preload` or with `Find`, it's only documented to work with `Scan`.